# PhpStorm: Use twig support in html files

Tags: html, twig, phpstorm

How can I use twig support in HTML files? Or generally, how can I add support for different languages to an existing file type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the used editor (html, twig,...) based on a given file name pattern per project. Just got to File->Settings -> Editor->File Types and add *.html as a pattern to the Twig editor.
The only downside is, that you can't assign a pattern to two editors ans switch around.
[image]